# Big grey area appears in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale-color-manual

I try to plot my data (x-axis - wavelengths. y-axis - variable "FLUO", fluorescence) with gglot on a color scale of the light environment ("light_env_Xday").

My code for plotting is:

```
light_scale_plot <- ggplot(data_table, aes(wavelengths, FLUO, group=light_env_Xday))+
  geom_line(aes(color=light_env_Xday), size=2)+
  scale_color_gradient2(name = bquote('Light Environment'~ (Wm^-2)), low="red", mid="green",
                        high="royalblue4") +  
  myplotting +
  xlim(660, 850) +
  ylim(0,0.65) 

light_scale_add <- light_scale_plot + ggtitle(" ") +
  xlab("Wavelenght [nm]") + ylab(bquote('ChlF'~ (mWm^-2 ~ sr^-1 ~ nm^-1)))


print(light_scale_add)
```

My input data is a data frame where: 1/ species (separate lines in the plot), 2/ light environment, 3/ wavelengths (x-axis), and 4/ FLUO (y-axis) are the columns.

```
species light_env_Xday wavelengths country FLUO SD
1    ACER       17.20762    335.7353 FINLAND    0  0
2    ACER       17.20762    336.1149 FINLAND    0  0
3    ACER       17.20762    336.4944 FINLAND    0  0
4    ACER       17.20762    336.8739 FINLAND    0  0
5    ACER       17.20762    337.2535 FINLAND    0  0
6    ACER       17.20762    337.6330 FINLAND    0  0
```

When I try to plot it with my code above, it delivers a big grey area. What can be the reason?
[image]

EDIT: When I use geom_point instead of geom_line, the problem does NOT appear.

Comment: The first thing I could think of is that there might be NAs in your colour variable, but it's hard to know for sure without a reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks. There are no NAs in my data so that is not the reason

Comment: ?  myplotting  what is the mypplotting?